# Light Sql Database

Tags: c++, .net, sql, database, sqlite

I am developing a .Net client application (written in C++) and I would like to integrate with a light sql database.
I have considered the use of SqlLite or SqlExpress.

Which other options are available? Which would be the better option?

Comment: What did you end up going with?  Did the options below help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

1. [Sqllite](http://www.sqlite.org/):  No install - just dll.  Very light, powerful and proven (they claim to be the most installed database in the world).
2. [Sql Compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx):  No install - just a dll, doesn't support all of the sql syntax like sql express or sql server.
3. [SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx):  Lighter than SQL server and is SQL syntax compatible.
4. [SQL LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx):  Still has an installer but doesn't need a windows service running.  sqlserver.exe starts on demand.  Supports the SQL syntax of SQL server and express.

This may also help out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx

If this is a desktop light app - then I would recommend sqlite or sqlcompact and possibly localdb if you need more complete t-sql capabilities.  The simplicity of just needing to copy a binary to access the DB in-proc is great for a client app.  Be aware that LocalDB/SQLExpress still has an installer and SQLExpress adds windows services to the clients box which might be overkill and add complexity.